# URL Rewriting Removing "&" to have clean search URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have Googled all the query string stuff and can't find a solution for my situation:

I would like this URL:
http://domain.com/?s=keyword&geo-radius=100&geo-lat=0&geo-lng=0&categories=0&locations=0&dir-search=yes

Become this one:
http://domain.com/?s=keyword

And remove all the the stuff including &

Thanks for help, this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RwriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(s=[^&]*)&.+
RewriteRule ^$ /?%1 [L,R]
```